# show a div before the title

Tags: views, theming, navigation

I'm using an accordion list. In my file views-views-accordion.tpl.php want to print a div before the title of each article. I'm using the latest version of drupal and views. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many ways of achieving this:

1. You can either preprocess it inside template.php file. The title has a #prefix and a #suffix theme key when preprocessing it with hook_preprocess_node().
2. Install delta blocks and turn convert the page into block and place the block accordingly.